# Android Gallery start position

Tags: android, indexing, gallery

I have an 
pictureGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);

howto set index to picture 10 as sample and simulate a click on  img 10 ?

thx

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select picture 10 just need to:

```
pictureGallery.setSelection(10);
```

To simulate a click on img 10, you can simply run the respective OnItemClicked code for the position 10.

Comment: It works  with  adapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); thx alot :)